# css - auto strech buttons horizontally

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to figure out how to use this [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp)

How do I modify it, so that buttons stretch to fill the entire page width?

I want to add buttons dynamically but don't know their width in advace.

Here it is in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqc05vz3/)

The relevant clipping of the CSS code:

```
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 15%; // <------ hardcoded width 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use external code sites to post code. Stackoverflow has you covered with snippets. Learn to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use flex. Add a wrapping div set to `display: flex` and add `flex-basis: 100%` to `.tablink`.

```css
.tab-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-container">
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>
</div>
```

Here's a great [flexbox cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#justify-content).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve this. Since the elements tabs getting used is adding dynamically you should remove the hardcoded width on it like mentioned in your comment and add a parent div to the buttons with property `display:flex`.
Replace your HTML part where the buttons are rendered with this

```
 <div class="tabBar">
 <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>
</div>
```

And add this to css

```
.tabBar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;

}
```

A working demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yash009/akvcyr51/9/)

Answer (score -1):

Changing the width to 25% will do the trick.